# Aucorrelation function

Tags: python

I have a `".txt"` file with extracted signals, which contains two columns of data. The first column is part time and the second column contains the flow data of this signal.

How can I calculate the period of this signal using the autocorrelation function in Python?

PS: The signal is already filtered.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you yet taken the time to read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? I also recomment the in-depth article [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Cheers!

Comment: autocorrelation is not a function in Python. You probably need numpy to do this
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing you are going to want to do is load the data. You might start with:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
signals = genfromtxt('yourfile.txt')
```

And as suggested by Fabio Picchi you could potentially continue using numpy to do your correlation.